# Salesforce: Birthday Apex Scheduler Questions

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, scheduler

I have written an Apex Scheduler class to send an email when a colleagues Birthday is 2 days away. I have created a contact with a birthday 2 days away. The contact's birthday is the July 29, 2012. Today's date is July 27, 2012.

I'm stuck. I don't get an error message or anything. I have scheduled the class to run today at 12. I didn't get an email (either telling me it was someone's birthday (success) or an error message from Salesforce telling me my code could not run (failure)

To trouble shoot, I also tried if (contact.Next_Birthday__c = : system.Today().addDays(2)) for the email method and got an incompatible types error. Next_Birthday__c is a date field, so I'm unsure of why the types are incompatible or why this SOQL statement doesn't work.

Any advice would be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
global class BirthdayNameOptions implements Schedulable{
  global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx)
  {
    sendBirthdayEmail();
  }

  public void sendBirthdayEmail()
  {
    for(Contact con : [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Next_Birthday__c = : system.Today().addDays(2)])
    {
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      mail.setTemplateId('00XJ0000000M31w');
      mail.setTargetObjectId('005J0000000');
      mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
      Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail });
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Have you visited: ***SFDC->Setup->Administration Setup->Scheduled Jobs*** Is there any record there of your class executing? If so are there any errors or exceptions? Also, just extending the *schedulable* class doesn't necessarily mean it will execute, you actually have the schedule the job in the org by creating a `CronTrigger` sobject

Comment: Jordan, the class is in scheduled jobs. Can you tell me more about this CronTrigger Object? How would I start this?

Comment: If it's in the Scheduled Jobs page, then you've already created the CronTrigger record that you're interested in. You most likely did it with the `System.schedule()` method.

Comment: This really should be a time-based workflow, using a scheduled class to send an email seems like serious overkill

Comment: @Ralph, the birthday email needs to recur every year. Time-based workflows only work once and then terminate

Comment: @JCD, I used the "Schedule Apex" button to schedule my class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set the `targetObjectId` of your outbound email message to the Contact whose birthday it is, rather than hardcoding it...the value `005J0000000` in your code doesn't seem to be a valid ID either, which could be causing you to not receive the email. For testing purposes you'd want to make sure the Contact record's email is set to yours, so you receive the notification. Also, you only get 10 calls to `Messaging.sendEmail()` per execution, so I bulkified this a bit for you. Give this a shot:

```
global class BirthdayNameOptions implements Schedulable {
    global void execute (SchedulableContext ctx) {
        sendBirthdayEmail();
    }
    public void sendBirthdayEmail() {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for ( Contact con : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Next_Birthday__c = : system.Today().addDays(2)] ) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTemplateId('00XJ0000000M31w');
            mail.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            mails.add(mail);
        }
        if ( mails.size() > 0 )
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails, false);
    }
}
```